# What is the difference between the words concede, admit and accept?

Tags: meaning

In which situations is the word **concede** used, in which situations is the word **admit** used, and in which situations is the word **accept** used?

Comment: What have you found by looking in dictionaries?

Answer (score 4):

Concede implies reluctance or a change of mind. "I concede your point" means that I reluctantly accept it, or I go back on my previous opinion and now agree with you. Accept is more neutral; "I accept your point" would be valid if I originally agreed with it, and if I didn't.

Admit (in the context of "I admit your point is true") means to concede something as true, again it implies reluctance. Just in my opinion, it doesn't imply as much of a change of heart as concede does. Admit also has the meaning to confess, as in "I admit I ate all the blancmange, but it was a crime of passion".

Answer (score 0):

**Concede:** To acknowledge, often reluctantly, as being true e.g.

> He finally conceded that she was right.

**Admit:** To grant to be real, valid, or true; acknowledge e.g.

> admit the truth.

**Accept:** To agree to take (a duty or responsibility), to answer affirmatively e.g.

> accept an invitation.